# How to enable pop-up for authentication in airprint on ios devices?

Tags: ios, windows, airprint

I have hosted the AirPrint Service from a windows 7 pc. I want to enable the authentication dialogue while printing from ios devices. Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the `HttpListener` socket of you ipp servie request(Airprint) is bound with `HttpListenerBasicIdentity`. This prompts the authentication popup in IOS device.

Further, following `air=user,password` text record must be set in DNS-SD while hosting airprint service.

Reading :  [Bonjour Print Specification](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/printing-specification/bonjourprinting-1.2.pdf)